# Rails: Proper work flow to shred XML data into relational SQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have a Rails project and I used Migrations to setup the database schema (I'm using sqlite3). I have a XML file that I want to insert into my database. What's the best way to approach this? I'm thinking there's some Ruby script that I can write once and use to parse the XML file and insert it into my database, but intuitively it feels like this is a common problem and should have already been automated in the Ruby/Rails world. I guess some people would call this XML shredding, but querying Google hasn't turned up much for me.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

[db/seeds.rb](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2009/09/05/planting-the-seeds) could be a good place to put the data.

Comment: are there built in scripts to easily map between XML nodes and data in the YAML format?